# Spinner won't show value selected

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I've referred to these questions and tried changing the text color and background color and it's not working. The issue is I'm selecting items in my drop down, but nothing is being displayed, even my logs aren't logging anything, I tried setting the first item as default and that doesn't work either.

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

private lateinit var spinner: Spinner
private val list: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()

spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner2)
list.add("String1")
list.add("string2")

spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)

spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterViwe<*>?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "nothing selected")
    }

    override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SELECTED ITEM " + list[p2])
    }
}

spinner.setSelection(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out, I'm populating the spinner on a separate thread and for some reason it was showing the values, but my array that populates the spinner adapter was still empty, I resolved it by moving everything into my background thread